# Por qué recibo el error File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module __import__(name) y como lo puedo solucionar?

Tags: django, python-2.7, setuptools

Hola estoy tratando de instalar django pero para ello primero debo instalar el setuptools y pip cuando ejecuto el el primero me sale el error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], que puedo hacer, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te da ese error por que tienes instalado python 2.7 y esa versión de setuptools requiere python 3.x

Comment: ok gracias, sabes donde puedo conseguir una versión para ese python??

Comment: Creo que la version 44.0.0 todavia funciona para python 2.7, puedes instalarla con pip, https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/44.0.0/

Comment: @KevinRamirezZavalza por favor, añade tus comentarios como respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Te da ese error por que tienes instalado python 2.7 y esa versión de setuptools requiere python 3.x

Creo que la version 44.0.0 todavía funciona para python 2.7, puedes instalarla con pip, pypi.org/project/setuptools/44.0.0